# Need help in inputting string and long using Scanner

Tags: java

I am inputting two long numbers and then two Strings. But it is taking only one string. Why?

```
long n,m;
String s1,s2;
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
n=s.nextLong();
m=s.nextLong();
s1=s.nextLine();
s2=s.nextLine();
System.out.println(s1+"    "+s2);
```

What should I do to stop `nextLong()` taking `\n`?

**EDIT**
Problem not solved

```
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=s.nextLong();
        m=s.nextLong();
        s.nextLine();
        s1=s.nextLine();
        s2=s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("s1:"+"\ns2:"+s2);
```

Output

```
s1:
s2:asas
```

Comment: Clarify "only one string". You realize that you will have to enter two lines of input here, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, i guess it should stop taking \n

```
       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        long n=s.nextLong();
        long m=s.nextLong();            
        String s1=s.next();
        String s2=s.next();
        System.out.println(s1+"    "+s2);
```